# Homework help with Standard Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a homework problem in which I'm not certain where to start:

Let $X$ be a random variable with $N (0, 1)$ distribution. Show that

$E(X^n) =\left\lbrace{\begin{array}{cc}
0 & \text{if $n$ is odd} \\ 
(n-1)(n-3)....3.1 &  \text{if $n$ is even}
\end{array}}\right.  $

Any pointers much appreciated.

Comment: I have answered with hints. You can reply by commenting here.

Comment: OK, I think I'm starting to get it. thanks for putting me on the right track.

Comment: I suppose you got it by now. I've updated my answer with the complete solution.

Comment: Thanx, I got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pdf of $X \sim N(0, 1)$ is $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2}$. Therefore,

$\text{E}(X^n) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^n e^{-x^2/2} \, dx$.

Now, for odd $n$, the integrand is an odd function, therefore the value of the integral is $0$ (as the integration is over a symmetric interval). For even $n$, the integrand is even, so we can write the integral as

$\text{E}(X^n) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} 2 \times \displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}x^n e^{-x^2/2} \, dx = \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}} \displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}x^n e^{-x^2/2} \, dx$

Let $t = x^2/2$. Then $dt = x\,dx \Rightarrow dx = dt/x = dt/\sqrt t$, and $0 < t < \infty$.

$\begin{align}
\text{E}(X^n) & = \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}} \displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}(2t)^{n/2} e^{-t} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt t} \, dt\\
& = 2^{n/2} \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}} \displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}t^{(n - 1)/2} e^{-t} \, dt\\
& = 2^{n/2} \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}} \Gamma\left(\dfrac{n - 1}{2} + 1\right)\\
& = 2^{n/2} \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}} \left(\dfrac{n - 1}{2}\right) \Gamma\left(\dfrac{n - 1}{2}\right)\\
& = 2^{n/2} \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}} \left(\dfrac{n - 1}{2}\right) \left(\dfrac{n - 3}{2}\right) \cdots \left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\\
& = 2^{n/2} \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}} \dfrac{(n - 1)(n - 3) \cdots 1}{2^{n/2}}\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}\\
& = \boxed{(n - 1)(n - 3) \cdots 1}
\end{align}$